# How do I change video sequencer playback range?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I imported a video and can’t seem to figure out how to adjust the playback range in the sequencer to start at zero. See below. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set play head at the first frame - press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd>,

then set play head at the last frame - press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd>